# Appending models to list

Tags: r

I have problem with creating list of models.
Suppose I've created model:

```
> rp <- rpart(V41 ~ ., data=learnData, method="class")
```

If I'm creating list straight, thats OK:

```
> ll <- list(rp, rp, rp)
> class(ll[[1]])
[1] "rpart"
> class(ll[[2]])
[1] "rpart"
> class(ll[[3]])
[1] "rpart"
```

But if I'm trying to append model to already created list,
models changing their class to data.frame:

```
> ll <- list(rp)
> ll <- append(ll, rp)
> class(ll[[1]])
[1] "rpart"
> class(ll[[2]])
[1] "data.frame"
```

What's a reason of this behavior and how can I append model to list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `append` is used to add elements to a vector.

To add elements to a list, use `list`.  Try:

```
fit1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
fit2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)

x <- list(fit1, fit2)
str(x, max.level=1)

List of 2
 $ :List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ :List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
```

You should now have a list of `lm` objects:

```
> class(x[[1]])
[1] "lm"
```

To append to an existing list, use `list` as follows:

```
x <- list(fit1)
x <- list(x, fit2)
```

Answer (score 12):

Andrie's solution:

```
x <- list(fit1)
x <- list(x, fit2)
```

doesn't work because it results in a `list` with `list` and `lm` components:

```
sapply(x,class)
# [1] "list" "lm"
```

you need to append a `list` to a `list` using `c` to get the desired behavior:

```
x <- list(fit1)
x <- c(x, list(fit2))
sapply(x,class)
# [1] "lm" "lm"
x <- c(x, list(fit3))
sapply(x,class)
# [1] "lm" "lm" "lm"
```

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scene, append simply works by using `c` (just type `append` and enter in the command line to see its source code). If you check the help for `c`, you'll find interesting things in the examples there (check the "do not use" part).

I remember this from a recent other question, or perhaps it was recently on R chat, but cannot recall which it was, so if somebody else can point to it?

In any case, for what you want:

```
ll<-c(ll, list(rp))
```

or if you insist on using `append`:

```
ll<-append(ll, list(rp))
```